# Search for a file and store the path in a variable

Tags: windows, shell, powershell

I am trying to search for 2 files in a directory tree and delete them. I want to **keep** the path of the file that had been deleted.

So far that's what I have:

```
#set the path to search for the file
$path = ".\"

#File name
$file = "GeneratedCode.cs"
$file2 = "TypedEnums.cs"

#Look for the file and delete every instance of it in all directories.
Get-Childitem $path -include $file -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}



#Look for the file and delete every instance of it in all directories.

Get-Childitem $path -include $file2 -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}
```

EDIT: 
I forgot to mention that I want to delete every instance of the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store the result of the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to a variable lets say `$filesToDelete`. Then you could simple pipe the object to the `Remove-Item` cmdlet (you don't need the `foreach` there):

```
$filesToDelete = Get-Childitem $path -include $file -recurse
$filesToDelete | Remove-Item
```

Comment: I want to delete every instance of the files so that's why I'm using foreach.(EDITED the question)

Comment: This will also delete every instance of the file.

Comment: ok I see, so would I have to make 2 variables e.g $filesToDelete and $filesToDelete2 with $file2 in order to delete the files? because the files are together  in every folder.

Comment: `$filesToDelete` will contain all files that matches your include condition regardless of the directory. So if you have two files  e. g. abc1.cs in /tmp and abc1.cs in /tmp2, both will be stored within the variable. If you pipe the objects to the Remove-Item cmdlet, **both** will be deleted.

Comment: That's Perfect Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, i ran into some problems when i try to run the code u gave me it only gives me whats inside the file not the path.

Comment: Then you have a Get-Content somewhere. Get-ChildItem only returns the items (not the content).

Comment: yea i forgot about the the Get-Content. It works perfectly ! cheers.